# SHOW SLAVE HOSTS; has an empty Host-output. How to get the slave-hosts?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replication, slave

I want to get all slaves-hosts from my master-host. So I thought, that `SHOW SLAVE HOSTS`; would be a good idea. Unfortunately, I get an empty host-column-output.

Do you know what I can do?
`SHOW PROCESSLIST` works with an empty host-list too.

Comment: when you do a `show processlist` on the master do you see any process that looks like `Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for b...`?

Answer (score 4):

You should use --report-host option on slaves.
Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-replica.html#sysvar_report_host